# git workflow for case where collaborators cannot see each other's work only main owner can

Tags: git, git-branch

Going to work on a project where I will be handling back end development and some guy would be handling front end development. How can I setup the project on git so that the front end developer cannot see the code of back-end ?

**I thought of separate branches :-**

1. Master (backend + Frontend)
2. Backend
3. Frontend (frontend developer will have only access to this branch )

But after some R&D I came to know that its not possible in Git.

What are the alternatives ?

Comment: `How can I setup the project on git so that the front end developer cannot see the code of back-end ?` Whats the benefit of that?

Comment: did you read the question description ?

Comment: my clients want backend code to be only accessible by backend developers

Comment: Create two distinct repositories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Protected branches isn't available with Git alone. BitBucket (a Git repository hosting) [provides it](http://blog.bitbucket.org/2013/09/16/take-control-with-branch-restrictions/) since Q4 2013.

But it is cleaner to work with **separate repos** (one got backend, one for frontend, and one for grouping them together through **[submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules)**)

That way, the relevant group of developers clones only the relevant repo it needs, and can manage as many branches as they want in said repo.